# How to use android studio and Xcode log format on real device

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

I want to debug the flutter application in android-studio and Xcode with the real phone device, could i directly log the message out at these two tools when i meet the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to debug a physical device connected to the computer(As you mentioned Android Studio and Xcode), use the `print()` function. It will show the logs in both Android Studio and Xcode.

or

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
```

Import this and use as

```
developer.log('log me', name: 'my.app.category');
```

Check details [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging).

Also, check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors) for dumping errors when the app suddenly stops.

Comment: Instead of dart side, is it the same as when i directly code `log.i` in android side and `print` in iOS side?

Comment: dart side print command will also print on xcode console like ```log.i```

Answer (score 1):

For android you can open terminal and execute :

adb logcat [options]
// make sure that adb is in PATH or you need to work on the adb folder

look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)